# API Authentication using multiple Authentication Providers

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0

This topic is one that feels like it should be documented better - or perhaps I am using the wrong terms when searching.

- I have several SPA apps that use various Oauth2 logins
  (ie. Okta, Facebook, Google) to authenticate and generate access
  tokens.
- These apps all access a common API backend (asp.net core).  All
  requests to the API have the Oauth2 access token attached as an Authorization header.

**How do I configure this single backend API to *validate* these access tokens** from one of a variety of providers, without knowing in advance which access token is attached, and *decode* a user email address that I can use for further authorization purposes?

*I have found much documentation on validating tokens from a descrete, known authorization provider, but very little on using multiple providers.  With all the apps out there that give you a choice of Oauth2 logons to choose from (StackOverflow among them), I thought this would be a more common problem.*

What am I missing!?

Comment: have you tried adding providers as mentioned here? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding a couple this way, but have been unable to make it work.  The document is for a "Web Application" rather than a backend API (not sure if that makes a difference(.  I think there must be more to it than just chaining the addProvider methods.  There is very little detail in this document.  If I were to get this working, how would I find the user information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was overthinking this after all.

Since I am dealing with an API backend, all I needed to do was to validate IDP Bearer tokens, not to create them. In the end, I was able to validate 3 ID providers using the folowing simple code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OKTA_SCHEME)
                .AddJwtBearer(ADFS_SCHEME, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = adfsConfig.authority;
                    options.Authority = adfsConfig.authority;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(GOOGLE_SCHEME, jwt => jwt.UseGoogle(
                    clientId: googleConfig.clientId
                ))
                .AddJwtBearer(OKTA_SCHEME, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = oktaConfig.authority;
                    options.Audience = oktaConfig.audience;
                });
```

Note that this required the installation of one additional nuget package to simplify the validation of the Google tokens, which don't appear to follow the standard: Hellang.Authentication.JwtBearer.Google.

At this point I can authorize using attributes like:

```
[Authorize(AuthorizationSchemes = OKTA_SCHEME)]
```

...or set up policies based on the schemes.

The second part problem was to link my various logons to users in a local database, which I ended up doing using a custom IClaimsTransformation that uses the information populated to ClaimsPrincipal to lookup a the user in my database, and add an "Employee" role claim, if they are found.

```
public class EmployeeClaims : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!principal.HasClaim(a => a.Type == "EmployeeNumber"))
        {
            Employee employee = lookupEmployee(principal);
            if (employee != null)
            {
                ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity();
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Employee"));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("EmployeeNumber", employee.EmployeeNumber.ToString()));
                principal.AddIdentity(id);
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
    private Employee lookupEmployee(ClaimsPrincipal principal) {
        string issuer = principal.Claims.Single(a => a.Type == "iss").Value;
        if (issuer.Contains("google.com"))
        ...
    }
}
```

This IClaimsTransformation is then registered  by:

```
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, EmployeeClaims>();
```

Now I can additionally authorize employees with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to identify the user in a consistent way in your APIs, then authorize requests based on the identity + scopes.

This will be very difficult when using many different token providers, as you are finding. Their access tokens are not designed for you to use in your own APIs.

A better mechanism is to use tokens only from your own Authorization Server, to support different login methods but also put your code in control. My [Federated Logins](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) blog post has further info.

Comment: So you are confirming my idea that this is not a simple problem.  I had been thinking that one solution would be to make my own /auth endpoint(s) to which I could submit these 3rd party access tokens, and issue a jwt of my own which could be used throughout the rest of the API.  But at that point I figured I was overthinking things.  Sounds like I wasn't?

Comment: It's not simple unfortunately - if you plug in an authorization server it will do the work of validating the third party tokens for you. As a short term option the UI could tell the API the token provider during API calls - perhaps via a custom header. The deeper problem then is that the API may not be able to get claims it needs from the third party tokens.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the correct way to address this situation is to build a Custom Authentication Handler as documented here: https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/implementing-custom-authentication-scheme-and-handler-in-aspnet-core-3x

In this Authentication Handler I can **decode the token**, assert that the issuer is a **member of a whitelist**, **validate the access token** using the issuer's public key, and use the rest of the token to **build the Identity** I need for further authorization.

At least now I have a better idea what to search for, and I'm not completely re-inventing the authentication mechanism!

Comment: Yep - when you're dealing with JWTs that's a common approach. You may find that access tokens from Google and Facebook are opaque strings and not JWTs though - worth checking that first.

Comment: Good point.  But the tokens I have been dealing with so far (from ADFS, Okta, and Google ID tokens) all appear to be JWTs with sufficient information for the above.